# In category theory, does $X \leq Y$ have a nice characterization in terms of the existence of a morphism $X \rightarrow Y$?

Tags: category-theory

Given objects $X$ and $Y$ of a category, write $X \leq Y$ iff for all objects $A$ and $B$ and all arrows $f : A \rightarrow B$, we have that if $f$ factors through $X$, then $f$ factors through $Y$. Thus the statement $X \leq Y$ is somehow expressing the idea that $X$ is "smaller" or "more narrow" than $Y$.

**Question.** Does the statement $X \leq Y$ have a nice characterization in terms of the existence of an arrow $X \rightarrow Y$ having a certain property?

(Probably there is an obvious answer, but I'm not very good at category theory, so everyone's help is very much appreciated.)

Comment: I knew about ordering relation for subobjects , but I was not aware of this more general definition. Does it have a standard name? where can I read more about it?

Comment: @magma, sorry I made it up, so I can't offer any references. Perhaps ask Zhen.

Comment: @ZhenLin, hey magma and I are interested in learning more about the $\leq$ relation; do you know of any references?

Comment: I am not aware of any. Being a retract (= split subobject) is a condition that comes up occasionally, but not enough to be studied on its own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The situation in $\mathbf{Set}$ turns out to be generic: in any category, $X \le Y$ if and only if there exists a *split* monomorphism $X \to Y$, or equivalently, if and only if there exists a *split* epimorphism $Y \to X$.

Indeed, the morphism $\mathrm{id} : X \to X$ factors through $X$, so if $X \le Y$, then there must exist $s : X \to Y$ and $r : Y \to X$ such that $r \circ s = \mathrm{id}_X$; conversely, given such $s : X \to Y$ and $r : Y \to X$, for any $f : A \to X$ and $g : X \to B$, we have $g \circ f = (g \circ r) \circ (s \circ f)$, so indeed $X \le Y$.

Comment: This can't be quite right; surely $0 \leq X$ for all sets $X$, however there is no split monomorphism $0 \rightarrow X$ unless $X \cong 0$.

Comment: You draw the wrong conclusion. Rather, $\emptyset \nleq X$ if $X$ is non-empty.

Comment: Not really getting it. Why is $\emptyset \not\leq X$ whenever $X$ is non-empty?

Comment: @user18921 $\emptyset \to \emptyset$ factors through $\emptyset$, but cannot possibly factor through $X$ if $X$ is non-empty.

Comment: @ThomasBelulovich, thanks I see now.

Comment: So, this means that this order relation is NOT a good generalization of the subset relation. Right?

Comment: Well, it's not a generalisation at all.

Comment: @magma, it was meant to capture the natural order on the object of $\mathrm{Set}$, but in a way that is useful in other categories. I am not sure it succeeds.